# Syntax error - PHP

Tags: php

Hi Dreamweaver says there is a syntax error on the following line. Is it right?

```
if (!in_array(array_reverse(explode(".",strtolower($file['name'])))[0],$allowedExtensions))
```

Comment: What does the error say apart from just syntax error?

Comment: did you try running the script? what error did you get?

Comment: Never say "I got an error".  Say "I got this error" and then **paste the entire error verbatim into your question** because we can't read your mind.

Comment: I get a lot of incorrect error messages from dreamweaver CS5. Why don't you just run the code and let PHP tell you if anything is wrong? @AndyLester Dreamweaver just says "syntax error at line nnn" as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexing the return value of a function is not supported in the version of PHP in use. Upgrade to a newer version, or turn it into separate statements.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not parsing for php 5.4 which is what is required to understand the `function()[0]` syntax.

Also your parameted for in_array() are incorrect

bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver is the **CULPRIT** !

Your code is just fine. I tried your code and it works fine.
Since you haven't disclosed us the variables.  `$file` and `$allowedExtensions`.  I assume this is what you must be doing.

Also, the `if` loop is *just fine*.

Get a new editor like **PHPStorm** or **Eclipse for PHP**

---

```
<?php
$file=array('name'=>'test.gif');
$allowedExtensions=array('.gif','.jpg','.png');
if (!in_array(array_reverse(explode(".",strtolower($file['name'])))[0],$allowedExtensions))
{
    echo "Valid File Extension";
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid File Extension";
}
```